# how client can send credential request to authentication server in kerberos authentication scheme code in java

Tags: java, kerberos

i am trying to implement kerberos authentication system in grid computing environment. in this project each node can communicate with the other nodes by authenticating its self using kerberos scheme. the first node send a credential request to authentication server which responds to that request by sending credential(session key and ticket) encrypted using client key. then client can decrypts it and get a copy of session key and forwards the ticket to the node which he wants to communicate. the ticket is encrypted using server key.

but i don't know how to start. or how client  can sends credential request to the authentication server?  are this is done by sending xml message to that server?
can any one helps me and i'll be thankful.

Comment: What transport do you use?

Comment: http over TCP/IP protocol

Comment: in this project clients and application servers are peers which called nodes and each node can communicates with other nodes to perform one complex task in parallel. the node can be a single computer, cluster or a complete organization.

Comment: No, this is not what I am meant. How do you establish the HTTP connection. Java's URL connection? Commons HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

Java URL Connection does this. Read the [Oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html) for.